# ie7/ie8: Unknown Runtime Error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, zclip

I am working on a script that is using [jQuery zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) and I keep running into this issue with IE7/IE8:

```
glue: function (elem, appendElem, stylesToAdd) {
        // glue to DOM element
        // elem can be ID or actual DOM element object
        this.domElement = ZeroClipboard.$(elem);

        // float just above object, or zIndex 99 if dom element isn't set
        var zIndex = 99;
        if (this.domElement.style.zIndex) {
            zIndex = parseInt(this.domElement.style.zIndex, 10) + 1;
        }

        if (typeof(appendElem) == 'string') {
            appendElem = ZeroClipboard.$(appendElem);
        } else if (typeof(appendElem) == 'undefined') {
            appendElem = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        }

        // find X/Y position of domElement
        var box = ZeroClipboard.getDOMObjectPosition(this.domElement, appendElem);

        // create floating DIV above element
        this.div = document.createElement('div');
        this.div.className = "zclip";
        this.div.id = "zclip-" + this.movieId;
        $(this.domElement).data('zclipId', 'zclip-' + this.movieId);
        var style = this.div.style;
        style.position = 'absolute';
        style.left = '' + box.left + 'px';
        style.top = '' + box.top + 'px';
        style.width = '' + box.width + 'px';
        style.height = '' + box.height + 'px';
        style.zIndex = zIndex;

        if (typeof(stylesToAdd) == 'object') {
            for (addedStyle in stylesToAdd) {
                style[addedStyle] = stylesToAdd[addedStyle];
            }
        }

        appendElem.appendChild(this.div);
        // ISSUE IS REPORTED BELOW IN IE7/IE8 
        this.div.innerHTML = this.getHTML(box.width, box.height);
    },

    getHTML: function (width, height) {
        // return HTML for movie
        var html = '';
        var flashvars = 'id=' + this.id + '&width=' + width + '&height=' + height;

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/)) {
            // IE gets an OBJECT tag
            var protocol = location.href.match(/^https/i) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
            html += '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="' + protocol + 'download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" id="' + this.movieId + '" align="middle"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" /><param name="movie" value="' + ZeroClipboard.moviePath + '" /><param name="loop" value="false" /><param name="menu" value="false" /><param name="quality" value="best" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><param name="flashvars" value="' + flashvars + '"/><param name="wmode" value="transparent"/></object>';
        } else {
            // all other browsers get an EMBED tag
            html += '<embed id="' + this.movieId + '" src="' + ZeroClipboard.moviePath + '" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" name="' + this.movieId + '" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="' + flashvars + '" wmode="transparent" />';
        }
        return html;
    },
```

To be more specific, the issue in the above code is here:

```
this.div.innerHTML = this.getHTML(box.width, box.height);
```

And the error is:

```
Unknown Runtime Error (line 304, char 3)
```

I have searched high and low via google and came across this generic issue for IE users but their solutions include what is already in the script, so, what else could be causing this?

Comment: you should use the $.html() function to update the innerHTML of an element. so you would do: $(this.div).html(this.getHTML(w, h));

Comment: @Derek - Thanks! I actually just did that right before seeing your comment! Can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: if you're using jQuery you should leverage its functionality... use the .css() function to update the style attribute, for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the `$.html()` function to update the `innerHTML` of an element. so you would do: `$(this.div).html(this.getHTML(w, h));`

if you're using jQuery you should leverage its functionality... use the `.css()` function to update the style attribute, for instance